# How I do use fetch API and store response in the state?

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

I have to get a file from the server, After the component is rendered, that contains information from cities, and I must assign it to **"citiesData"** in the state. But the data is not received because it is not seen in the output.

what is the issue with my fetch?

**server file:**

[image]

**IranMap**(the file seems to have a problem in fetch):

```
import React from 'react';
import './IranMap.css';
import CityModal from './CityModal';

class IranMap extends React.Component {

    state = {
        error: null,
        citiesData: null,
        selectedCity: null,
        isModalOpen: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/cities')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    citiesData: result
                });
            },
                (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    error
                });
                }
            )
    }

    cityClicked = (id) => (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(`http://localhost:9000/cities/${id}`,{method: 'GET'})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedCity: result,
                    isModalOpen: true
                });
            })
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: false,
        });
    };

    render() {
        if(this.state.error){
            return <div>Error: {this.state.error.message}</div>;
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="map-container">

                        {(this.state.citiesData || []).map((record) => (
                            <div
                                key={record.id}
                                className="city-name"
                                style={{
                                    top: `${record.top}%`,
                                    left: `${record.left}%`,
                                }}
                                onClick={this.cityClicked(record.id)}
                            >
                                {record.name}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <CityModal
                        city={this.state.selectedCity}
                        isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
                        onClose={this.closeModal}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default IranMap;
```

This is my output. it should be show cities name. but this is empty:

[image]

Comment: Now the problem of showing cities is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is render the entire object,u cant do that, try the render each element, The second part of my answer is that you should use an asynchronous task.

I hope my answer guided you

Comment: Thanks. I show only a part of my code. I want to complete it. In the render section, each element is mapped with the map method. I just must do fetch. My question only is about how to do fetch.